Simplify object with JSONata
If I have an object that looks like:
{ "inventory":
  {
    "apple": {"type": "fruit", "region": "Washington"},
    "orange": {"type": "fruit", "region": "Florida"}
  }
}

What would be the JSONata expression to convert it to:
{
  "apple": "Washington",
  "orange": "Florida"
} 


With some digging, I was able to come up with this transform
$zip(inventory.$keys(), inventory.*) {
    $[0]: $[1].region
}

Is there a better way to solve this?

$merge($spread($.inventory).{ $keys(): *.region })
or
$spread($.inventory).{ $keys(): *.region } ~> $merge
Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/f9a27f8a
